# the approach to building a web application

Tags: database, pdf, web, report

This is the scenario i have:

im developing a web app that will list down all the details of a car that the user picks from a list. I have a database of all car models, makes, sizes, prices etc. Besides i also have the price trend for the past 5 yrs. You may assume that i have a few of such tables and the data volume is about 10s of thousands of records.

My online application should be able to let the user pick his choice of one car model and optionally provide his address. With just this user input, i want to be able to generate a pdf report with the following information:

- Comparison of selected car model with other cars manufactured in the same country. (e.g, if user selected, honda, i want to compare it with toyota, which comes from the same country)
- Comparion of selected car with other car of similar type (eg. sedan vs sedan)
- Price trend of the car for the last 5 yrs - Nearest car workshops in user's neighbourhood within a radius of 10km (if user has given me his address)

i will be drawing out several other data from my database.

I would like to present this report instantly, say within 3 minutes to the user. So now the question, is, what software/tools/program/database etc should i be using, taking in consideration the huge amount of data and the need to present this in the fastest possible time as a pdf report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are whole lot of possibilities. You can use PHP (or) Java (or) .Net (or) so on...for web application, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc., as database (If data is really big and grows like anything daily you may consider Hbase also) It dependency on how soon you want your product out in the market and how much scalable it should be and how much comfortable you are with any of those technologies.

Some technologies support nice user interface, some may not but strong in other area of web application.

How much money/time you have for development, licensing also plays role in deciding answer for this question.

Comment: For server side programming, is ror a better choice compared to Java or .net?  I see that some Web with large database use ror. Twitter for instance,that is if my info is up to date.

Comment: I have no experience with ror (assuming Ruby on Rails), but heard/read it is very userful one for web devlopement. I vote +1 for it.